# Fastest Algorithm to calculate Graph pebbling number?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am interested in [Graph Pebbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_pebbling), and in particular what are the fastest known algorithm is to find the pebbling number of a graph. Also, i am interested whether there are lower limits on the runtime of such algorithms.

I am aware of the paper by Nandor Sieben proposing [a graph pebbling algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1651), however it is 10 years old and I am interested whether there have been improvements on this algorithm, therefore my question is:

> What is the fastest algorithm calculating the graph pebbling number of a Graph?

Comment: this [2019 article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X18303431) on pebbling numbers only mentions the Sieben algorithm, so I would presume that is all there is.